# WP authors page

Tags: author

I'm kind of new to WP and am starting to delve into the WP codex and don't know how to figure out how to change a default slug. Say I have a url to an individual author like so:

https://www.website.com/author/authors-name/

How would I change /'author'/ to something else like 'people' or 'agents' ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the code below to your theme's function.php or in your own custom plugin...

```
function custom_author_slug() {  
    global $wp_rewrite;  
    $new_slug = 'people';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $new_slug;  
}
add_action('init', 'custom_author_slug');
```

After you do it go to your admin then to Settings > Permalinks and click "Save Changes" which will trigger a flush of the WordPress rewrite rules (or you can [flush rewrite rules programmatically](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)).

There is also an [Edit Author Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/) plugin that you could use, but I'd recommend going the code route when possible since it's unlikely something you will need to change again and it's such a small change.